# Browser instance get killed while running light house through puppeteer on the second page

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, lighthouse

On my application I am running light house on various page in my application, in an orderly manner for example first on the launch page then again once I log in one more time and so on.

So after launch page and when I am trying to go for the authentication the browser instance is getting killed. I am also retrieving the page metrics and windows metrics. Here below is my code,

```
(async () => {
    const launchOptions = {
        headless: false,
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
        args: ['--start-maximized',
            '--disable-web-security',
            '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process'],
        defaultViewport: null
    };
    const lightHouseopts = {
        logLevel: 'info',
        output: 'json',
        disableDeviceEmulation: false,
        defaultViewport: {
            width: 1200,
            height: 900
        },
        chromeFlags: ['--disable-mobile-emulation']
    };
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
    const url = "";
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    try {
        await page.goto(url);
        const metrics = await page.metrics();
        await influx.write([{
            measurement: 'launch_page_puppeteer_evaluation',
            tags: {
                page: 'launchpagepuppeteer'
            },
            fields: metrics
        }])

        const performanceTiming = JSON.parse(
            await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(window.performance.timing))
        );

        performanceWindowsMetrics(performanceTiming, 'launchpagewindowsperformance', 'launch_page_windows_performance')
        const configLightHouse = null;
        const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch(lightHouseopts);
        lightHouseopts.port = chrome.port;

        const resp = await util.promisify(request)(`http://localhost:${lightHouseopts.port}/json/version`);
        const { webSocketDebuggerUrl } = JSON.parse(resp.body);
        const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: webSocketDebuggerUrl });

        // Run Lighthouse
        const { lhr } = await lighthouse(page.url(), lightHouseopts, configLightHouse);
        await browser.disconnect();
        await chrome.kill();

        const json = reportGenerator.generateReport(lhr, 'json');
        const audits = JSON.parse(json).audits; // Lighthouse audits
        const first_contentful_paint = audits['first-contentful-paint'].displayValue;
        const total_blocking_time = audits['total-blocking-time'].displayValue;
        const time_to_interactive = audits['interactive'].displayValue;

        console.log(`\n
        Lighthouse metrics: 
         First Contentful Paint: ${first_contentful_paint}, 
        ⌛️ Total Blocking Time: ${total_blocking_time},
         Time To Interactive: ${time_to_interactive}`);

        const time = new Date().getTime();
        const html = reportGenerator.generateReport(lhr, 'html');
        fs.writeFile(`report-${time}.html`, html, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        await userNamePage.enterUserName(page, inputFiles.mySiteUserName);
        await passwordPage.enterPassword(page, inputFiles.mySitPassword);
        await page.waitFor(500);


        await browser.disconnect();
        await chrome.kill();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {

        await page.waitFor(10000);
        console.log("Closing the browser session")
        await browser.close();
    }
})();
```

Getting broswer instance killed.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? At the end of your script you login and then kill the browser with `chrome.kill` - what are you trying to achieve at it is not clear from your question and that last part makes no sense without knowing why you are doing it.

Comment: Sorry to hear this Graham, I guess description is not clear, let me elaborate,
Step 1:
     i. Launch the page on browser using puppeteer.
    ii. Trigger the lighthouse, page metrics and windows evaluation
    iii. Close the instance on the lighthouse only
Step 2:
    i. Log in to the application by entering user name and password.
   ii. Trigger the lighthouse, page metrics and windows evaluation
   iii. Close the instance on the lighthouse and puppeteer.

Comment: So after the auditing the launch page my intention to login to the application, see the image attached.

Comment: Right so from what I can see there you enter the username and password but don't trigger anything after that, is the problem that the browser is being closed or is it just that it isn't logging in? i.e. does the browser stay open but on the login page. I also presume all of the audit stuff before works as expected?

Comment: Graham actually it is failing before that, If I disable the lighthouse piece of code then it is working fine and user is able to logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out by some research, thought I can help the community if someone same searching for the answer.

**First the root cause** that cause the browser getting killed, by default Light House is not responsible for keeping the session, it run on the session maintained by the browser. That why when LightHouse triggered from Puppeteer, the session is maintained by Puppeteer not the browser used by the Puppeteer.

Solution: You need to copy the session token or id from the Puppeteer and pass it on to Google Light House when it is called, you can put it in the argument list.

Inside the blow code:

```
const lightHouseopts = {
        logLevel: 'info',
        output: 'json',
        disableDeviceEmulation: false,
        defaultViewport: {
            width: 1200,
            height: 900
        },
        chromeFlags: ['--disable-mobile-emulation']
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this answer, we have implemented the the same framework and we are looking the answer.